# Building a portfolio tracker char based on a list of transactions: a formula/approach is incorrect

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a chart, which tracks month-to-month portfolio assets:

[image]

The initial dataset is a basic transaction list (`A:G`). Next, I'm trying to define a dataset (`I:L`), where the column `I` contains first days and `J:L` columns have actual balances at those moments.

A `J:2` formula is:

```
=INDEX(array_constrain(filter(SORT($A$2:$G;1;FALSE); $B$2:$B = J$1; $A$2:$A < $I2); 1; 7); 1; 7)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as expected. The formula is also quite complicated, so I wish it can be simpler.

Any help and links are highly appreciated.

**p.s.** If you are not in a personal challenge mode, then I suggest you to look at this portfolio tracker example: https://investmentmoats.com/stock-market-commentary/portfolio-management/introducing-our-free-stock-portfolio-tracker-spreadsheet/

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet with toy data?

Comment: @kishkin sure, here is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-FrXrXvzLz49FejlM_CHPF4XyIOyigDHztD2Ybnq6k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: missed it a bit. Do you mind sharing it again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

On `I2` you can add:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:A), 1, true)
```

This  basically gets the unique dates and sorts them automatically.

On `J1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE($B$2:B), 1, true))
```

Which is the same but using column B and transposing so it's horizontal.

And now the big one, on `J2`:

```
=
ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    (I2:I<>"")*(J1:1<>"");
    IFERROR(
      VLOOKUP(
        I2:I&"␟"&J1:1;
        QUERY(
          {ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&"␟"&B2:B),G2:G};
          "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1"
        );
        2;
        true
      );
      0
    );
    ""
  )
)
```

The basic idea is to use `QUERY` to make the sum of the values and then use `VLOOKUP` to find which sum should go to that cell. Because you cannot lookup 2 cells at the same time, I join both columns using a unit separator `␟` to separate the 2 values. This could be any other character that it will never appear but this has this precise function. Add a few conditionals to handle errors and empty values, and you have the result.

### Reference

- [UNIQUE (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
- [SORT (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [TRANSPOSE (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [QUERY (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [VLOOKUP  (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: If you'd like a deeper explanation of the last formula let me know :)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it does not work now. Cells have 0 values only: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-FrXrXvzLz49FejlM_CHPF4XyIOyigDHztD2Ybnq6k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The 'total' column is the running total. In other words, it contains the aggregated values.

Comment: I found some fantastic examples, so please don't spend time on it :) https://investmentmoats.com/stock-market-commentary/portfolio-management/introducing-our-free-stock-portfolio-tracker-spreadsheet/